# Return a WP_REST_Response from an inner function (and not from the root callback)

Tags: rest-api

If I call this custom endpoint on the server:

```
register_rest_route( "example", "/name", [
    "methods" => "POST",
    "permission_callback" => "__return_true",
    "callback" => function( $req ) {
        return new \WP_REST_Response([ 
            "code" => "internal_err",
            "message" => "Name not found",
        ], 500)
    }   
]);
```

I correctly get a response with a 500 status code and the following error on the client:

```
{ 
    code: "internal_err", 
    message: "Name not found"
}
```

However, if I try to set the response not directly as the return value of the endpoint's main callback, but from an inner function, `WP_REST_Response` doesn't "kill" the request, instead the response is passed to the parent function (in this case, to `sayFirstName`) like a regular return value:

```
register_rest_route( "fotoroom", "/name", [
    "methods" => "POST",
    "permission_callback" => "__return_true",
    "callback" => function( $req ) {        

        function getFullName() {
            return new \WP_REST_Response([
                "code" => "internal_err",
                "message" => "Name not found"
            ], 500 );                   
        }
        
        function sayFirstName() {
            $name = getFullName(); // This is now a WP_REST_Response object...
            return $name->firstName;  // ...so it tries to find "firstName" on the WP_REST_Response object
        }

        return sayFirstName(); 

    }

]);
```

In this case, what I get on the client is a response with a 200 status code and no data...

Alternatively, I can throw an exception and set a try/catch block in the endpoint's main callback:

```
register_rest_route( "example", "/name-2", [
    "methods" => "POST",
    "permission_callback" => "__return_true",
    "callback" => function( $req ) {    
        
        try {

            function getFullName() {
                throw new \Exception( "Name not found" );                   
            }
            
            function sayFirstName() {
                $name = getFullName(); 
                return $name->firstName;  
            }

            return sayFirstName(); 

        } catch( \Throwable $e ) {

            return new \WP_REST_Response([
                "code" => "internal_err",
                "message" => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500 );                   

        }

    }

]);
```

This gives me again a response with a 500 status code and the following error on the client:

```
{ 
    code: "internal_err", 
    message: "Name not found"
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to send a response directly from an inner function, or if maybe I am completely missing something.

Comment: "instead the response is passed to the parent function (in this case, to `sayFirstName`)" - yes, because that's indeed how it works in PHP. And your "try-catch" worked in returning the response with the 500 status because that's what your "catch" returned, which becomes the return value of your endpoint's main callback.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but I would like to send a response error directly from `sayFirstName` rather than having an exception bubble up to the callback. Do you know if that can be done by any chance?

Comment: `return $name->firstName ?? $name;` is an example of doing it.. using the code without the "catch".

Comment: You can't `return` from an "inner" function any further up the chain that the scope that called the function. You have to return from that inner function, and then return that result. You're using the result of a function for dual purposes i.e. using a REST API response as a source of data for another function... not how it's meant to be done.  Create a single source of the data you're querying, and use that as the source for properly buidling separate Rest API responses.